# Xcode simulator different to preview

Tags: xcode

I am drawing an interface in *XIB* files using *xcode 7*, everything looks fine in the designer, and in the preview for all my targeted devices.
However when I use the simulator, or install to my *iphone 5* the layout changes completely, colours are lost, controls are bunched up and/or completely moved.

**I have no constraint errors or warnings**, it does not make sense.

I am also using *autolayout*.

any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Cleaned the project, restarted Xcode and the simulator? Do the screen sizes match?

Comment: yes, restarted xcode, and the simulator, tried real phone too. screensizes match as well